# Check for ID while ignoring part of the ID name

Tags: jquery, string, forms

I'm currently adding a placeholder attributes to input fields by targeting them by ID.

```
$('#spectrum-form-id-number-6904_4').attr('placeholder', 'First Name');
$('#spectrum-form-id-number-6904_5').attr('placeholder', 'Last Name');
$('#spectrum-form-id-number-6904_6').attr('placeholder', 'Email');
```

I need to be able to target them without the "6904" part of the ID, as the form is dynamically generated and these 4 digits will vary, but the prefix "spectrum-form-id-number-" and the ending number "_4" (or _5, _6) will be the same across all generated forms.

Comment: Kermit, check out my answer, is it helpful to you?

Comment: @RaviManiyar Yes it was. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi @Kermit - please upvote it if you found it useful solution and you can remove your answer which is more like a comment! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code segment to refer to all the spectrum elements whose digits are going to be dynamic:

```
$("div:regex(id, spectrum-form-id-number-.*)");
```

It will spit out the DOM element and you will be able to further play with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).
E.g.

```
$('[id^="spectrum-form-id-number-"][id$="_4"]').attr('placeholder', 'First Name');
$('[id^="spectrum-form-id-number-"][id$="_5"]').attr('placeholder', 'Last Name');
$('[id^="spectrum-form-id-number-"][id$="_6"]').attr('placeholder', 'Email');
```

> [attr^=value]
>   Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value.
>
> [attr$=value]
>   Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is suffixed (followed) by value.